# How to transform results from related metrics into a single state value

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana

I am using Prometheus and Grafana to collect and display pod/container status for a Kubernetes cluster. I'm collecting the information from the following metrics:

```
kube_pod_container_status_running
kube_pod_container_status_terminated
kube_pod_container_status_waiting
```

**Note**: I left a fourth metric, `kube_pod_container_status_ready` out as it seems to be a duplicate of `kube_pod_container_status_running`. If I am mistaken, please let me know what the difference is.

Each metric returns a 0 or 1 result, where 1 indicates the container is currently in that state (e.g. runnning). I'm making the assumption that at any given time, only one of these metrics should have a value of 1 for a given set of labels representing a specific container in the cluster. From what I've seen, each metric collects the same set of label dimensions.

What I would like to do is display a table of container information of interest (pod, container, namespace, etc.) plus a column indicating the current state (Running, Terminated, etc.). I may need to include other queries to integrate other information not available from this current set.

I have tried a couple of experiments that have allowed me to collect the information into a single table view, but cannot figure out how to translate the 3 metric results into a single state representation. So, for example: [running=1, terminated=0, waiting=0] into "Running", or [running=0, terminated=0, waiting=1] into "Waiting".

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You metrics seems rather strange, and even against Prometheus' recommendations.
Usually such metrics would be in format `kube_pod_container_status{status="waiting"}`.

You can convert your metrics to conventional format, and display them in table.

Use query

```
label_replace(
 label_replace(
  {__name__=~"kube_pod_container_status_.*"} == 1
  ,"status","$1","__name__","kube_pod_container_status_(.*)")
,"__name__","kube_pod_container_status","__name__",".*")
```

And switch [format](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/prometheus/query-editor/#format) of you query (under your query editor) to "Table".

If you'll use panel "Table", you'll see metrics like you described.

Comment: Wow. Took me a little while to figure out what that's doing (still not sure I understand it all). It's like you created a new metric, or something. Pretty slick.

Comment: @JosephGagnon, I've used `label_replace` two times: 1. introduce new label based on metric name, 2. rename metric. Second step is strictly speaking unnecessary, but this kind of approach is usually used in relabeling on scraping step, so I kept it.

Comment: I re-read your response and finally understood your comment about the metrics being "strange". I agree, but I did not define these. Something else in my cluster has done this.

Answer (score 1):

Idea (not real copy&paste code): use math and "merge" 3 different metrics into one value, which can be value mapped to string on the Grafana level.

Example math:

```
(kube_pod_container_status_running * 1) +
(kube_pod_container_status_terminated * 10) +
(kube_pod_container_status_waiting * 100)
```

So in this case Grafana value mapping will be:

```
1 => running
10 => terminated
100 => waiting
```